# Changing the names on a legend

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2, plotnine

I am trying to change the names on my legend of this plot. Using this code in pandas i get this error message (below). The first part of this code works but its something to do with the combine part that it doesnt like.

```
plot3 + labs(colour = 'Location area', lables = c('Urban', 'Rural', 'No data'))
```

error message;

```
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

What i am looking for is this plot to have the lengend title of 'Location area' and the 1,2 and 3 to be renamed 'Urban', 'Rural' and No data'. Let me know if more data/info is needed for this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legend key labels are set via the `labels` argument of the `scale`. But the main issue is that you use `c()` which is R code. As you are using `plotnine` and Python you have to use square brackets:

Using a simple example based on `mtcars`:

```
from plotnine import ggplot, geom_point, aes, stat_smooth, facet_wrap, scale_color_discrete, labs
from plotnine.data import mtcars

(ggplot(mtcars, aes('wt', 'mpg', color='factor(gear)'))
 + geom_point()
 + stat_smooth(method='lm')
 + scale_color_discrete(labels = ['Urban', 'Rural', 'No data'])
 + facet_wrap('~gear')
 + labs(color = 'Location Area'))
```

[image]